# Pyspark: Filter dataframe based on field and time period in other dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to select rows in df1 that fulfill the following conditions:

```
1) df1.number == df2.number
2) df1.timestamp >= df2.startdate
3) df1.timestamp <= df2.enddate
```

Both dataframes have different columns but share the number column:

**df1**

| number | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 213 | 2020-10-26T07:55:34 |
| 432 | 2020-11-26T07:55:34 |

**df2**

| number | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 213 | 2020-10-26 | 2020-10-28 |
| 432 | 2020-10-13 | 2020-11-26 |

I'm having trouble figuring this out. I think a left-semi join in combination with a filter/where clause should do it, but it's not working:

```py
df3 = df1.join(df2, on=['number'], how='left_semi').where((df1.timestamp >= df2.startdate) & (df1.timestamp <= df2.enddate))
```

Grateful for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot apply the filter after the join because the columns in `df2` no longer exists after the join.

Instead, you can put all the conditions into the `on` part of the join:

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, (df1.number == df2.number) & (df1.timestamp >= df2.startdate) & (df1.timestamp <= df2.enddate), how='left_semi')
```

It might also be better to cast the columns to the same type before comparing, e.g.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df3 = df1.join(df2, 
    (df1.number == df2.number) & 
    (F.to_date(df1.timestamp) >= F.to_date(df2.startdate)) & 
    (F.to_date(df1.timestamp) <= F.to_date(df2.enddate)),
    'left_semi'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_date


val df1 = Seq((213, "2020-10-26T07:55:34"), (432, "2020-11-26T07:55:34"))
  .toDF("number", "timestamp")

val df2 = Seq(
  (213, "2020-10-26", "2020-10-28"),
  (432, "2020-10-13", "2020-11-26")
).toDF("number", "startdate", "enddate")

val df3 = df1.join(df2,
  df1.col("number") === df2.col("number") &&
    to_date(df1.col("timestamp")) >= df2.col("startdate") &&
    to_date(df1.col("timestamp")) <= df2.col("enddate")
  , "left_semi")

df3.show(false)
//  +------+-------------------+
//  |number|timestamp          |
//  +------+-------------------+
//  |213   |2020-10-26T07:55:34|
//  |432   |2020-11-26T07:55:34|
//  +------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Have you tested this? I suspect you didn't because I think you would've got a syntax error. `val df3 = ...`, `===` and `&&` aren't python.